# WordPress embeds in AJAX inserted content

Tags: ajax, embed

I have a page that is calling in the content from other posts (a custom post type, specifically) and inserting it into the page. It all works great, but I'm losing the functionality of WordPress taking youtube (and other embeddable links) and automatically inserting the embedded video.

I've tried `apply_filters( 'the_content', $my_content );`, but I think that filter isn't even available via `admin-ajax.php`.

I of course already call `do_shortcode( $my_content )`, but what can I use, in similar fashion, to get the embeddable links to embed?

UPDATE:

In response to bonger's answer, I've updated the code to this:

`wpautop( do_shortcode( $wp_embed->run_shortcode( $my_content ) ) )`

($wp_embed was globalized before this line of code)

Note that the `wpautop()` and `do_shortcode()` are totally irrelevant to this issue, but I put them in here just for completeness. This code is outputting the youtube url as a link to the youtube video, but not embedding the video in the page.

Comment: I globalized `$post` and `$wp_embed` objects in my ajax callback, and then in my content I added `do_shortcode( $wp_embed->autoembed( get_the_content( '' ) ) )`. This did the trick. Thanks for the pointers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution is amazingly simple here:

You're just missing a single line of code in your *ajax* callback, namely:

```
global $post;
```

where I assume you're using:

```
$post = get_post( $post_id );
```

The reason is that there's a global post check in the `WP_Embed::shortcode()` method.

More details in my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142597/26350).

Comment: Whoah, that did it. Simply globalizing $post. Uncanny. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you - it's a weird solution, I know ;-)

Comment: I was just about to jump out the window! Thanks, you saved my life :)

Comment: @DarrenCooney thanks for commenting, I'm glad to hear it helped ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some weirdness with `[embed]` shortcodes where you have to run them through `WP_Embed::run_shortcode()`, eg

```
    if ( strpos( $my_content, '[embed]' ) !== false ) {
        global $wp_embed;
        $my_content = $wp_embed->run_shortcode( $my_content );
    }
    $my_content = do_shortcode( $my_content );
```

**Update**: however as no providers are registered this won't work as you noticed(!), so I think the easiest thing to do is to call `wp_oembed_get()` direct:

```
            $args = array();
            global $content_width;
            $args['width'] = $content_width ? $content_width : 300;
            // Simplistic parse - look for a url on its own line.
            $lines = explode( "\n", $my_content );
            foreach ( $lines as $i => $line ) {
                $line = trim( $line );
                if ( stripos( $line, 'http' ) === 0 ) {
                    if ( $oembed_html = wp_oembed_get( $line, $args ) ) {
                        $lines[$i] = $oembed_html;
                    }
                }
            }
            $my_content = implode( "\n", $lines );
```

You may want to use transients to avoid repeated calls to the provider - here's a version of stuff I use:

```
// Wrapper around wp_oembed_get() to use transients.
function wpse175427_oembed_get( $url, $args ) {
    global $wpse175427_oembed_transient_expiration;
    if ( $wpse175427_oembed_transient_expiration ) {
        $transient_key = md5( $url . '_' . wpse175427_reduce_array( $args ) );
        if ( $oembed_html = get_transient( $transient_key ) ) {
            return $oembed_html;
        }
    }

    //add_filter( 'oembed_fetch_url', 'wpse175427_oembed_fetch_url', 10, 3 );
    //add_filter( 'oembed_result', 'wpse175427_oembed_result', 10, 3 );
    if ( $oembed_html = wp_oembed_get( $url, $args ) ) {
        if ( $wpse175427_oembed_transient_expiration ) {
            set_transient( $transient_key, $oembed_html, $wpse175427_oembed_transient_expiration );
        }
        return $oembed_html;
    }
    return '';
}

// Helper to stringify args array (for transient key).
function wpse175427_reduce_array( $arr ) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ( $arr as $key => $val ) {
        $ret[] = '`' . $key  . '`=`' . $val . '`';
    }
    return implode( ',', $ret );
}
```

Then set the global in your ajax callback, eg

```
            global $wpse175427_oembed_transient_expiration;
            $wpse175427_oembed_transient_expiration = DAY_IN_SECONDS;
```

and call `wpse175427_oembed_get()` instead of `wp_oembed_get()`.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't seem to work. I also meant moreso for inline video links. Although I even attempted wrapping them in embed and then doing this. It seems to just be making it a link.

Comment: Okay none of the providers are registered. I'll update the answer with calling `wp_oembed_get()` directly...

Comment: I think you're making it more complex than it has to be, just declare `$post` as global in the ajax callback, where `$post = get_post( $post_id )`,  and you're done ;-)

Comment: @birgire Ah, excellent!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `get_the_content()`, like:

```
$my_content = get_the_content();
$my_content = apply_filters('the_content', $my_content);
```

Comment: Getting the content is not the issue. I already have the content. Also, I've already stated that filters don't work via AJAX.