# How to use oEmbeds on Post Content during AJAX requests

Tags: posts, ajax, oembed

I have an AJAX request that returns a post. The `post_content` has links to Twitter, YouTube, TED and other platforms that are registered as oEmbed providers in a default, vanilla WordPress install. By now, the WordPress oEmbed handler does not register them and displays plain links and nothing else.

How can I fetch content via AJAX with oEmbed support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually this was quite easy – when you know what's missing: The current post ID for the global `$wp_embed` object, so it knows what to refer to. The reason is simple: oEmbeds get cached as post meta data, so without knowing the ID, the MarkUp can't get fetched and replaced in the content.

```
// grab a post from the database

/** @var \WP_Embed $wp_embed */
global $wp_embed;

/** @var \WP_Post $post; */
// Add the fetched posts ID and add it to the global object
$wp_embed->post_ID = $post->ID;

// Execute the [embed] shortcode
$wp_embed->run_shortcode( $post->post_content );

// Execute the oEmbed handlers for plain links on the own line
$wp_embed->autoembed( $post->post_content );
```

That's it.

*More [in depth](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142597/385) info about oEmbed and caching can be found in a related answer by @birgire.*

Comment: yes I thought too it would be more involved, before digging through similar stuff [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142125/heartbeat-api-oembed/142597#142597) ;-)

Comment: I think it is better to use `$wp_embed->autoembed( $post->post_content );`, isn't it @kaiser?

Comment: @cybmeta Actually you need both. They have a different purpose (plain links and `[embed]` shortcode).

Comment: I forgot about `[embed]`, I never use it.

Comment: @birgire Updated with a link to your answer.

Comment: thanks @kaiser, this problem seems to popup in various ways, so it's nice to have a simple workaround as you demonstrate.